# В чем ошибка (фигурные скобки)?

Tags: .net

```
        using System.Net.Http;

        new MultipartFormDataContent()
        {
            Add()
        };
```

Пишет

> Имя "Add" отсутствует в текущем контекст

Comment: Так написано же, не видит он эту функцию. Надо создать ее либо вызвать через класс.

Comment: @JurijJazdanov это метод

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что так писать нельзя. Во-первых, нельзя вызвать произвольный метод через инициализатор объекта. Во-вторых, у метода Add должны быть еще и параметры.

Вот так будет работать:

```
   new MultipartFormDataContent
   {
       ctx, // Неявный вызов метода Add с одним аргументом,
       {ctx, a}, // Неявный вызов метода Add с двумя аргументами,
       {ctx, a, b}, // Неявный вызов метода Add с тремя аргументами,
   };
```

Особо обращу внимание, что так можно вызывать **только** метод Add - и только если создаваемый объект реализует интерфейс `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Т.е. это костылик специально запиленный для Add? Почти как литералы списка/словаря в js/питоне.

Comment: Это не "костылик", а инициализатор коллекции.

Comment: Ну "сахарок", если будет угодно.